# Unable to post Tweets from another Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, twitter-oauth

I am Using Outh to add Twitter to my app.

Below are two UIViewControllers for login and posting tweets respectively.

1.SettingViewcontroller
 2.DetailViewcontroller

This code for  login to  twitter with SettingViewcontroller.

```
- (void)switchAction1:(UISwitch*)sender
   {
   if (sender.on)
    {
           if(_engine) 
       return;

      _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self]
   _engine.consumerKey = @"###";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"###"; 

   UIViewController *controller =[SA_OAuthTwitterController  controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

   DetailViewcontroller *detobj=[[DetailViewcontroller alloc]init];

 detobj.detail_enginne=_engine; 

   [detobj release];

    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
   }
  if(!sender.on)
  { 

NSLog(@"Logout section");

    }
}
```

And In DetailViewcontroller when action sheet button cliked the below code will executed.

```
    if ([detail_enginne isAuthorized]) 
    { 
      NSLog(@"engine availble");

               NSString *str=@"hai twitterrrrrrrrrrr";

             [detail_enginne sendUpdate:str];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Engine not availabele");
             }  
}
```

Here Iam unable  to send tweets from DetailViewcontroller.

How to achive this?

**Updated**

Iam loding Detail view using ViewDidload not Nib.

Detailview.m

this is actionSheet method for posting data to  facebook and twitter from DetailView

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    // For  facebook
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{


    if ([session resume])  {


        [self postToWall];

        NSLog(@"Post to wall");

    }
    else {

        self.loginDialog = nil;
        _loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];    
        [_loginDialog show];

    }


}                           

//  For twittter
  if(buttonIndex == 1)
  {         
    if(detail_enginne!=nil) 
    { 

        NSString *str=@" hai twitter  ";
        [detail_enginne sendUpdate:str];

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Not availabele");

    }
}
if(buttonIndex == 2)
{

    NSLog(@"cancel button ");


}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing is where you are getting user credentials?

I don't know, For what purpose you are checking your button index.
You try like this also,

```
if ([detail_enginne isAuthorized])
{
  NSLog(@"engine availble");
  NSString *str=@"hai twitterrrrrrrrrrr";
  [detail_enginne sendUpdate:str];
}
 else
{
   NSLog(@"Engine not availabele");
}
```

From your code,

```
    - (void)switchAction1:(UISwitch*)sender
       {
       if (sender.on)
        {
               if(_engine) 
           return;

          _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self]
         _engine.consumerKey = @"###";
          _engine.consumerSecret = @"###"; 

         UIViewController *controller =[SA_OAuthTwitterController  controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];
     if(controller)
{
    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES]; //Here You will show your login screen twitter
}


//After getting credentials , You do this

   DetailViewcontroller *detobj=[[DetailViewcontroller alloc]init];

     detobj.detail_enginne=_engine;  // this **detobj** should be used for presenting detailView

       [detobj release];
       }
      if(!sender.on)
      { 

    NSLog(@"Logout section");

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have action sheet button with the name  "Twitter" in Detailviewcontroller.When user click tis button data should have to post.I tried ur code but not working.U please chek my question, I have updated.Thanks

Comment: When the switch.on is True. Before getting login credentials and After getting credentials.If tat is after getting credentials , Comment the lines,

Comment: _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self]
   _engine.consumerKey = @"###";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"###"; 

   UIViewController *controller =[SA_OAuthTwitterController  controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

Comment: Switch on is for login.That is working fine.The problem is Iam unable to access engine when I jump into Detailview.Iam in last stage of my project please do help.

Comment: I have updated the answer.Have a look. One more thing where you are presenting ur detail view.Can you show tat code.

Comment: Please chek it , I have added Detailview where Iam posting data.

Comment: @user824794 I asked where you are changing from setting view to detailview. How you are moving ??? Tat code i asked.